# Google Search API returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that queries the Google AJAX Search API and returns results. However, **all the results are currently coming back as "undefined".**

How can I fix this?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var resultsDiv = $('#resultsDiv');

        $.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&callback=jsonp',{q:"google",rsz:8,start:0},function(r){
            var results = r.responseData.results;
                var pageContainer = $('<div>',{className:'pageContainer'});
                for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                    pageContainer.append('<div class="webResult"><h2><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.title+'</a></h2><p>'+r.responseData.results.content+'</p><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.responseData.results.visibleUrl+'</a></div>');
                }
                resultsDiv.empty();
                pageContainer.append('<div class="clear"></div>').hide().appendTo(resultsDiv).fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the callback `callback=?`

Comment: You need to use jsonp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jsonp since it's returning a jsonp response

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0", 
  data: {q:"google",rsz:8,start:0},
  dataType: 'jsonp', //<---
  success: function(r){
        var results = r.responseData.results;
            var pageContainer = $('<div>',{className:'pageContainer'});
            for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                pageContainer.append('<div class="webResult"><h2><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.title+'</a></h2><p>'+r.responseData.results.content+'</p><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.responseData.results.visibleUrl+'</a></div>');
            }
            resultsDiv.empty();
            pageContainer.append('<div class="clear"></div>').hide().appendTo(resultsDiv).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bYSZg/

EDIT:

Here's why its displaying undefined.. you are getting your data correctly

```
pageContainer.append('<div class="webResult"><h2><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.title+'</a></h2><p>'+r.responseData.results.content+'</p><a href="'+r.responseData.results.unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.responseData.results.visibleUrl+'</a></div>');
```

should be

```
pageContainer.append('<div class="webResult"><h2><a href="'+r.responseData.results[i].unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.responseData.results[i].title+'</a></h2><p>'+r.responseData.results[i].content+'</p><a href="'+r.responseData.results[i].unescapedUrl+'" target="_blank">'+r.responseData.results[i].visibleUrl+'</a></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XhuH6/1/

Comment: are you using chrome?  if so expand the error to pinpoint what is causing it

Comment: See my updated answer.. you were incorrectly getting the data out of the jsonp response

Answer (score 0):

The result of the Ajax request is: jsonp({"responseData":... });
not {"responseData":... }

This code is evaluated at the time the 'success' callback is called.
I think all you have to do is to define a new function with name jsonp as follows:

```
function jsonp(r){
      var results = r.responseData.results;
      ....
}
```